# How to setup Apache NiFi using IIS as proxy

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, apache-nifi

I have Apache NiFi running on a Windows server. I've setup HTTPS access and connected it to my AD via LDAP for users authentication. The value of property `nifi.web.https.host` is `localhost` and `nifi.web.https.port` is 6444 and I'm able to access the web UI through https://localhost:6444/nifi with no issues.

I want now to setup NiFi to run behind IIS on the same server so IIS acts as a proxy. I've created a new site within IIS and configured the URL Rewrite rules in its web.config file as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<clear />
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
<rule name="NiFi Reverse Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost:6444/{R:1}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Both IIS and NiFi are using the same SSL certificate from my organization.

I've configured the `nifi.web.proxy.host` property in the `nifi.properties` file to `nifi01.myorg.com:443`.

I'm able to access https://nifi01.myorg.com/nifi from an external computer. I see the sign in page and am able to sign in successfully. However, after the authorization is completed, I'm redirected to https://localhost:6444/nifi. If in the same browser session I type in https://nifi01.myorg.com/nifi, then I can see the main Nifi workflow UI which tells me that the sign in process did work.

Can someone help me with the redirection that is happening to https://localhost:6444/nifi. Is there something that I'm missing in the web.config or nifi.properties files?

I found this article https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/113240/running-apache-nifi-behind-a-proxy-2.html that I've not been able to follow as don't know where in IIS the settings should go.

Comment: So what is "as below"? You showed nothing about your URL Rewrite rules.

Comment: Sorry @LexLi, I was having issues with formatting the XML . It's in there now.

Comment: It was the login process (part of NiFi) that sent its own redirection, to the actual URL `https://localhost:6444/nifi` instead of `https://nifi01.myorg.com/nifi`. If `nifi.web.proxy.host` is not the right way to go (I don't know much about NiFi), you might add a outbound rule in IIS to fix the URL in responses.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?