# how to use nifi.web.proxy.host and nifi.web.proxy.context.path?

Tags: haproxy, apache-nifi

I have deployed NiFi with Kerberos in a cluster and for accessing the UI I am using haproxy. I am able to access NiFi UI through the individual node URL but it's not working with the loadbalncer URL and getting following error

> System Error
>
> The request contained an invalid host header

I think it can be fixed by nifi.web.proxy.host and nifi.web.proxy.context.path parameters. I tried with this two parameters but the problem still remains.

Comment: check the official documentation: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#proxy_configuration if something still not clear, please edit your question and add details.

Comment: I have gone this document but its not clear. Still I am confuse what should i give the value for those parameters. If possible can you give some sample value for those parameters.

Comment: in the same documentation there is an example. `localhost:18443, proxyhost:443` for proxy host, and `/my-nifi` for proxy context. after that your url to nifi should be like this: `https://proxyhost:443/my-nifi/nifi`

Comment: I tried but its not working

Comment: Please edit your question and add details about infrastructure, nifi configs, and error you get (what exactly is not working).

Comment: I having the same problem as (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746218/how-to-setup-apache-nifi-using-iis-as-proxy?rq=1)

Comment: in case that you mentioned there was an issue of proxy configuration. describe your case or your question will remain unanswered.

Comment: provide the `nifi.web.*` properties from `nifi.properties`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue was pointed at in NiFi 1.5 [NIFI-4761](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4761).
To resolve this issue, whitelist the hostname used to access NiFi using the following parameter in the nifi.properties configuration file :

```
nifi.web.proxy.host = <host:port>
```

Its a comma-separated list of allowed HTTP Host header values to consider when NiFi is running securely and will be receiving requests to a different host[:port]. For example, when running in a Docker container or behind a proxy (e.g. localhost:18443, proxyhost:443). By default, this value is blank, meaning NiFi should allow only requests sent to the host[:port] that NiFi is bound to.